# Error using mount command within Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

The following Dockerfile throws an error when building it. Is there a way to be able to use `mount` with `overlay` while building the container?

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:15.10

RUN mkdir /var/data \
 && mkdir /var/data/delta \
 && mkdir /var/data/delta/changes \
 && mkdir /var/data/delta/workdir \
 && mkdir /var/data/merged \
 && mkdir /var/data/lower

RUN mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=/var/data/lower,upperdir=/var/data/delta/changes,workdir=/var/data/delta/workdir /var/data/merged
```

**Error**

...

```
Step 2 : RUN mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=/var/data/lower,upperdir=/var/data/delta/changes,workdir=/var/data/delta/workdir /var/data/merged
 ---> Running in 37434cc88e15
mount: overlay is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: cannot mount overlay read-only
Removing intermediate container 37434cc88e15
The command '/bin/sh -c mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=/var/data/lower,upperdir=/var/data/delta/changes,workdir=/var/data/delta/workdir /var/data/merged' returned a non-zero code: 32
```

**Note**

I tried running the below mount command on within a `ubuntu:15.10` container and it gives the same error. If the container is started with `--privileged` the command works.

Comment: why not do with `VOLUME` in `Dockerfile`?

Comment: They are not VOLUMES, other than /var/data/delta/changes none of them are mounting the hosts file system or exposing their data, the data would exist ONLY within the container. For example, a Jenkins installation would be on /var/data/lower and then ONLY the modified files would be exposed outside the container via  /var/data/delta/changes.

Comment: it's antipattern, vote down of course ! American i....!

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to be able to use `mount` with `overlay` while building the container?

Short answer: [No, and there won't be any time soon](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1916#issuecomment-118511676).

It seems the consensus is that any kind of privileged operation during build breaks the image portability contract, as it could potentially modify the host system. If a different system were to then pull and run such an image instead of building it from source, the host would be in an invalid state, from the perspective of the resultant container.

Remember, <kbd>docker build</kbd> works by completing each step/layer in the `Dockerfile` using (loosely) these actions:

1. Run the image of the last step/layer as a new container
2. Complete the operations for the current step/layer within the container
3. Commit the container (incl. new state) to a new image
4. Repeat for any further steps

Therefore, it's clearly possible for a privileged build operation to break out of the temporary container and touch the host in this scenario. No bueno.

So, what do?

---

## Solution 1 (baked-in mount)

**UPDATE — 2015-10-24: Fail. See Solution 2 below for a working implementation.**

*Note: YMMV depending upon Docker version, storage/graph driver, etc. Here's my <kbd>docker info</kbd>, for comparison:*

```
Containers: 12
Images: 283
Storage Driver: overlay
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 4.1.10-040110-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 15.04
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 7.598 GiB
Name: agthinkpad
ID: F6WH:LNV4:HH66:AHYY:OGNI:OTKN:UALY:RD52:R5L5:ZTGA:FYBT:SWA4
WARNING: No swap limit support
```

Well, I'm surprisingly finding it nigh impossible to bake the mount into an image via <kbd>docker commit</kbd>. The `/proc` filesystem, where a file representation of mount metadata is written by the kernel (more specifically `/proc/self/mounts`, from within a container), doesn't appear to be persisted by Docker at all. From what I can tell, anyway — `/var/lib/docker/overlay/<container-root-lower>/root/proc` is empty, and `/var/lib/docker/overlay/<container-root-upper>/upper/proc` doesn't exist.

I thought `/proc` could be manipulated via a volume, and did indeed find some 2+ year old references to bind mounting `/proc:/proc` to achieve things that probably nobody should even be attempting (like this, possibly? ), but it appears this doesn't work at all anymore. Attemping to bind mount `/proc` to a host directory or even just make a volume of it is now a fatal error, even with <kbd>docker run --privileged</kbd>:

```
Code: System error

Message: "/var/lib/docker/overlay/c091a331f26bed12f22f19d73b139ab0c5b9971ea24aabbfad9c6482805984c9/merged/proc"
 cannot be mounted because it is located inside "/proc"

Frames:
---
0: setupRootfs
Package: github.com/opencontainers/runc/libcontainer
File: rootfs_linux.go@37
---
1: Init
Package: github.com/opencontainers/runc/libcontainer.(*linuxStandardInit)
File: standard_init_linux.go@52
---
2: StartInitialization
Package: Error response from daemon: Cannot start container c091a331f26bed12f22f19d73b139ab0c5b9971ea24aabbfad9c6482805984c9: [8] System error: "/var/lib/docker/overlay/c091a331f26bed12f22f19d73b139ab0c5b9971ea24aabbfad9c6482805984c9/merged/proc" cannot be mounted because it is located inside "/proc"
```

In terms of a method that doesn't require running <kbd>mount …</kbd> inside containers spawned from the image via a startup/entrypoint script, I'm really not sure where to go from this point. Because `/proc/self/mounts` is managed by the kernel, let alone not writable, this may never be possible. Hopefully I'm overlooking something and someone can point me in the right direction.

<del>If you *must* do this during image compilation you can roll your own builder script by doing something like the following:

— Optionally, first create a `Dockerfile` and use the stock builder:

    FROM mybaseimg|scratch

    COPY ./a /tmp/a
    RUN foo
    …

`docker build -t mynewimg .`

— Write a shell script using a combination of: `CID=$(docker create mynewimg)`, [`docker cp …`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cp/), `docker start $CID`, `docker exec|run … $CID …`, `docker stop $CID`, `docker commit $CID mynewimg`, etc. *(Edit: Preferably, use the [API](https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/remote_api_client_libraries/)!)*

When you need to apply a privileged operation, you can escalate the `docker run` command, but `--privileged` is total overkill here. If you *think* you shouldn't need `--privileged` for something you almost certainly *don't*. For an OverlayFS/AuFS mount you will need to initialize `docker run` with `--cap-add=[SYS_ADMIN]`, and for Ubuntu (and possibly other) hosts with `AppArmor`, you also need `--security-opt=[apparmor:unconfined]` (or preferably an AppArmor profile which relaxes the necessary restrictions, instead of `unconfined`). I'm not sure about `SELinux`.</del>

---

## Solution 2 (runtime mounting)

**`host$`**<kbd>uname -a</kbd>

> Linux agthinkpad **4.1**.10-040110-generic #201510030837 SMP Sat Oct 3 12:38:41 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

**`host$`**<kbd>mkdir /tmp/overlay-test && cd /tmp/overlay-test</kbd>

**`./Dockerfile`**:

```
FROM debian:jessie

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl jq

WORKDIR /usr/local/sbin

# Locate and fetch the latest version of gosu
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "curl -o ./gosu -sSL \"$( \
      curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/tianon/gosu/releases/latest \
      | jq --raw-output \
        '.assets[] | select(.name==\"gosu-'$(dpkg --print-architecture)'\") | .browser_download_url' \
    )\" && chmod +x ./gosu"]

COPY ./entrypoint.sh ./entrypoint
RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint

# UPPERDIR and WORKDIR **MUST BE ON THE SAME FILESYSTEM**, so
#  instead of creating a VOLUME for UPPERDIR we have to create a 
#  parent directory for both UPPERDIR and WORKDIR, and then make
#  it the VOLUME. 
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "mkdir -p /var/overlay-test/{lower,upper/{data,work}} /mnt/overlay-test"]
VOLUME /var/overlay-test/upper

# Create a file named FOO in the lower/root branch
RUN touch /var/overlay-test/lower/FOO

ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint"]
```

**`./entrypoint.sh`**:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

cd /var/overlay-test
mount -t overlay -o lowerdir=lower,upperdir=upper/data,workdir=upper/work overlay /mnt/overlay-test
chown -R "$DUID":"$DGID" ./
chown root: ./upper/work
chmod 0750 ./upper/work

cd /mnt/overlay-test
exec gosu "$DUID":"$DGID" $@
```

**`host$`**<kbd>docker build -t overlay-test ./</kbd>

`Successfully built 582352b90f53`

OK, let's test it!

**Note:** Under an Ubuntu 15.04 host I had trouble deleting (overlay whiteout) any files that exist in the `lowerdir` via the mounted directory inside the container. This bug appears to be the culprit:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1480411 — *Edit: `rm` works all of a sudden and I can see the char file in `upper/data`, so I can only assume this is fixed and I received an updated package.*

**`host$`**<kbd>docker run -it --name=overlay-test --env="DUID=$(id -u)" --env="DGID=$(id -g)" --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN --security-opt=apparmor:unconfined overlay-test /bin/bash</kbd>

**`overlay-test$`**<kbd>id</kbd>

`uid=1000 gid=1000 groups=1000`

**`overlay-test$`**<kbd>mount | grep '/mnt/overlay-test'</kbd>

`overlay on /mnt/overlay-test type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=lower,upperdir=upper/data,workdir=upper/work)`

**`overlay-test$`**<kbd>pwd</kbd>

`/mnt/overlay-test`

**`overlay-test$`**<kbd>ls -Al | sed '/^t/d'</kbd>

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000    0 Oct 24 03:54 FOO
```

**`overlay-test$`**<kbd>touch BAR</kbd>

**`overlay-test$`**<kbd>ls -Al | sed '/^t/d'</kbd>

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000    0 Oct 24 04:21 BAR
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000    0 Oct 24 03:54 FOO
```

**`overlay-test$`**<kbd>ls -Al /var/overlay-test/{lower/,upper/*} | sed '/^t/d'</kbd>

```
ls: cannot open directory /var/overlay-test/upper/work: Permission denied

/var/overlay-test/lower:
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000 0 Oct 24 03:54 FOO

/var/overlay-test/upper/data:
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000 0 Oct 24 04:21 BAR
```

So far so good…let's try importing the volume from another container:

**`overlay-test$`**<kbd>exit</kbd>

**`host$`**<kbd>docker run --rm --user="$(id -u):$(id -g)" --volumes-from=overlay-test debian:jessie /bin/bash -c "ls -Al /var/overlay-test/upper/* | sed '/^t/d'"</kbd>

```
ls: cannot open directory /var/overlay-test/upper/work: Permission denied

/var/overlay-test/upper/data:
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000 0 Oct 24 05:32 BAR
```

Success! Note that you could also `RUN echo` the mount spec `>> /etc/fstab` in your `Dockerfile` and then `mount -a` inside the entrypoint script, but this method was quirky, in my experience.  I'm not sure why, but as there isn't a functional difference between the two methods, I didn't bother to investigate any further.

Clean-up: **`host$`**<kbd>docker rm -v overlay-test && docker rmi overlay-test</kbd>

---

Documentation for container runtime security in Docker:

https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#security-configuration
https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-linux-capabilities-and-lxc-configuration

Comment: Perhaps the mount command it not what I should be using as I do not want to mount volumes from the host system. What I want is to create a layered file system within the container and be able to expose only the folder with the modified files.

Comment: The idea is that I want to create a docker container for a program, say Jenkins, that has all files extracted but not exposed. Only new or modified files would be exposed by the container for easy and small back ups, not all of the files that compose Jenkins, which is what the Jenkins docker image currently does.

Comment: @Enzey that's exactly what my instructions are for! Just FYI, I needed a 4.x kernel to get the OverlayFS mount to run inside of the container. I'm also using Overlay as Docker's graph/storage driver and mount was still erroring inside the container, even after setting the correct permissions for container creation, seemingly because I was stacking Overlay file systems which was broken on the 3.19 kernel I was running. I think some 4.2 kernels have a regression, but I can confirm 4.10 works. Anyway, I'm pretty sure my answer tackles your use case, so you might want to read it again. :)

Comment: Regardless, you can not `RUN mount …` within a Dockerfile unless you use a non-default builder (check out [Dockramp](https://github.com/jlhawn/dockramp), for an example). It is simply impossible.

Comment: I did not get a chance to fully look into it but what you mentioned is what I want. I'll give it a try the next time I get a chance.

Comment: @Enzey I overhauled my answer and added a complete implementation/example that targets your use case. Hope it's of use!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93270/discussion-between-adrian-gunter-and-enzey).